# Postgresql how to use 2 table at the same time

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, filtering

This is the problem :
**Which quiz was the first “image checklist” quiz? What date was it published on?**
and I have 2 tables named B=**public.daily_agg_quiz_metrics** and A=**public.quiz_metadata**.     A table has variable **quiz_type** variable. B table has **date** variable. So how can I solve this problem? This is my approach but it is not working

```
SELECT  * 
FROM  public.quiz_metadata 
WHERE quiz_type ='image checklist' 
ORDER date BY ASC
```

Comment: The solution is going to involve a `JOIN` and that means knowing the relationship between the tables. You are going to need to update your question to provide the complete definitions for the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
select quiz_id, num_views from public.daily_agg_quiz_metrics
where quiz_id in
(select quiz_id from public.quiz_metadata
where quiz_type='image checklist'
order by published asc
limit 1)
```

Comment: It is a solution but steps over the relational nature of the query. This sort of thing is best done using a `JOIN`. See my answer.

Comment: Yes. But I didn't know that keyword yet at that time. Now I agree with you but this is much algorithmic and informative at the same time to a beginner who doesn't know join keyword IMO.

Comment: What it shows is that if you are going to delve into SQL you should at least read an introduction to basic SQL principles. `JOIN` being one of the most basic.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `JOIN` to accomplish your task:

```
SELECT 
    daily_agg_quiz_metrics.quiz_id, num_views 
FROM 
    public.daily_agg_quiz_metrics
JOIN
    public.quiz_metadata
ON 
    daily_agg_quiz_metrics.quiz_id = quiz_metadata.quizz_id
WHERE 
    quiz_type='image checklist'
ORDER BY 
    published asc
LIMIT 1
```